# Change date of birth format of view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Want to change date of birth format to dd/mm/yyy in laravel .
Actually i want it to be saved in dd/mm/yyyy format but it should be send to the database in yyyy/mm/dd format . How can it be done ?? . Here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Date of Birth:</label>
                  <span class="data_fields data_personal">{{ date_to_indian($cust_data->dob) }}</span> 
                  <span class="edit_fields edit_personal"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $cust_data->dob }}" name="dob"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can use carbon https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 2):

Use Carbon's `format()` method:

```
Carbon::parse($date)->format('d/m/Y');
```

If date is in Eloquent `$dates` property, just use `format()`:

```
$date->format('d/m/Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel accessor mutators in laravel. Put below code in your model

```
 protected $dates = [
    'dob',
];
//This method automatically save date Y-m-d format in database

public function setDobAttribute($date)
{
        $this->attributes['dob'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}

 //This method automatically fetch date d-m-Y format from database

public function getDobAttribute($date)
{
   return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

You must be use carbon class namespace as following:

```
use Carbon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<span class="edit_fields edit_personal"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($cust_data->dob )); ?>" name="dob"></span>
```

Comment: This format is working good but when i click on save the new date doesnt get saved . It shows the old date . The format has been changed but the date is not getting saved after editing

Comment: Check in db what date is being saved and what are you getting as output

Comment: Actually i want it to be saved in dd/mm/yyyy format but it should be send to the database in yyyy/mm/dd format . How can it be done ??

Comment: While sneding to the db again convert it to the desired format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Date Mutators`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) to convert a date to instances of [`Carbon`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which extends the PHP `DateTime` class to provide an assortment of helpful methods.

Add the following property in your model:

```
protected $dates = [
    'dob',
];
```

Then use it in your view as:

```
{{ $cust_data->dob->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

When retrieving attributes that are listed in your `$dates` property, they will automatically be cast to `Carbon` instances, allowing you to use any of Carbon's methods on your attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use [carbon date format method](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) `format()`

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($cust_data->dob)->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

OR

you can use [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) `date()` for it:

```
{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($cust_data->dob))}}
```

**Both are return same result but I recommend you to use Carbon because Carbon is inherited from PHP DateTime class.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try twig [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) here  `{{ $cust_data->dob | date('d-m-Y') }}`

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Date of Birth:</label>
                  <span class="data_fields data_personal">{{ $cust_data->dob | date('d-m-Y') }}</span> 
                  <span class="edit_fields edit_personal"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $cust_data->dob }}" name="dob"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$cust_data->dob->format('d/m/Y');`
for more options http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/